# Javascript's scrollTo() is not working when no bounce css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a single page application built with Vue. I'm trying to create a native-like view, with a no bounce and scroll to top when browsing the pages. The problem is that it doesn't scroll, when no bounce css is provided (overflow, width/height etc).

```js
document.getElementById('test').scrollTo({
    top: 1000,
    left: 0
})
```

```css
html {
    visibility: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    background-color: #edf2f9;
    color: #000000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow: hidden;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -ms-content-zooming: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overscroll-behavior-y: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    contain: layout size style;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

section {
    padding-top: 96px;
    padding-bottom: 96px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section>
        <div style="height: 5000px;" id="test">
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Can someone help me out, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the ID "test" for the section element.
The section is the element that has content that is larger than its own container and can therefore be scrolled. Therefore scrollTo can be applied to this element. The `<div>` below has no content larger than its own container, so it cannot be scrolled.

Comment: Still not working... ;-( I'm pretty sure that it's because of the CSS, but I don't know other way to make the page without bounce...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that there's a simple CSS setting, that can solve all bounce problems, without having to use `width: 100%; height: 100%;`. After that, scrolling works perfectly. I'm not sure about the browser compatibility, but it works on my latest MacOS and iOS, so I'll stick to it.

```
body {
    overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

Taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior